# Synchronize local TFS workspace with server

Tags: tfs

I've retrieved files with TFS 2008 and then deleted them manually using explorer.

The files still appears to be available locally in TeamExplorer. You know files only on the server are shown in gray text and files in the workspace are shown in black.

Is there a way to update the workspace, so TeamExplorer correctly will show which files are present on my local drive?

Answer (score 4):

Also, if you want to get rid of a file, don't ever just go out and delete it from the file system.  There's no integration between the file system and the TFS server*.  If you want to clear the local workspace, you need to "get specific version" on the files, specifying Changeset #1.

To do this,

1. Right click on the Source Explorer on the folder you want to clear out, and choose `Get Specific Version`
2. Change `Type` to `Changeset`
3. In the `Changeset` field, type the number 1.
4. Click both checkboxes to overwrite.

Once this process is done, TFS believes that you have an empty workspace.  If there are files left behind at this point, they can be deleted through the file system, as they were files that TFS didn't know about in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Use the Get Specific Version and then check the option "Overwrite all files even if the local version matches the specified version".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

go to the directory in a visual studio command window and type

```
tf get . /recursive /force
```